# How to disable auto show hints in JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm, WebStorm) on mouse over

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

How to disable auto show hints in *IntelliJ IDEA* on mouse over?

[image]

**Edit**:

This hint could be very big if you call existing method with incorrect parameters. It's very uncomfortable.

There are the same behaviour in *PyCharm*:

[image]

and *WebStorm*:

[image]

Comment: @vikingsteve If only I could :)

Comment: What does PyCharm have in common with the question?

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost, I edited my question to be more clear. You can see these tooltips in any of JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: But you want to keep the inspections activated? I.e. the little yellow and red marks on the right edge of the code panel?

Comment: @vikingsteve, yep, you are right.

Answer (score 17):

Those popups (or tooltips) has been my worst annoyance in the editor for a while. There is how I fixed it:
On the editor, at the bottom-right of the window, there is a head icon. Click it and uncheck the box "Import popup".

You can have a look at this guide (with images) to help you finding the checkbox:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/disabling-inspections.html

I hope that can help you

Comment: No, this is not a solution. This tooltips are related to inspections. I can't disable it without disabling inspections. I posted the request to Idea bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114803

Comment: This does not answer the question. It just removes "import popup" dialogs, there are many more tooltips than those!

Comment: That fixed it for me.  I need that import dialog to be temporarily off whilst I fix conflicts.  "Import ...." kept popping up making it difficult to work out the conflict.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TOTALLY: Open Settings (or Pereferences, if you are OS X user) dialog, choose **Editor | Inspections**.  On the **Mange tab** (right pane of the dialog) select **Copy**. Then click the language node. Here you can find the setion that is probably responsible for your tooltips and disable it. Or disable the whole language node, if you like. This way you have all the IDE features working and no tooltips at all. You can return back to Project Default inspections profile when you need it.

PARTIALLY: Try to disable the respected intention action. **Press Alt+Enter** when you see the tooltip, select the action from the list and press the **right arrow key**. In the context menu, **select "Disable"**.

From [JetBrains Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205823059-Can-I-disable-annoying-tooltips-suggestion-Alt-Enter-).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to uncheck the `Inlay Hints`.
For Windows 10 & PyCharm Community 2020.3.3 :

File > Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints

Uncheck `Show hints for:`